# am facing this error yet have installed sqlalchemy this problem when trying to run student.py to insert daata in table created

Tags: python-3.x

```
File "/home/tommi087/Desktop/Development/code/phase-3/python-p3-crud-with-sqlalchemy/student.py", line 1, in <module>
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

I tried to run `pip install sqlalchemy` so as to execute the code but haven't been resolved

Comment: "I *tried* to run pip install sqlalchemy" --- well, what happened when you did? Did it appear to succeed?  If it didn't succeed in installing, the error message is exactly what you'd expect.    Make sure that the `pip` you use on the command-line refers to the same Python installation you're using to run your code.   One way to ensure you have control of that is to say `/WHATEVER/PATH/TO/python -m pip` instead of just `pip`.